# Load Spring application context in a HiveMQ Plugin

Tags: spring, mqtt, hivemq

I am trying to load a Spring Application Context (xml) in a HiveMQ plugin. I seem unable to load the context because it cannot find the xml configuration. The `spring-context.xml` is located in "src\main\resources" and i try to load the context using:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml")
```

The error i get is the following:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Comment: It seems the spring-context.xml is not copied to the HiveMQ plugin jar file. Did you modify the Maven Shade configuration so the xml is included in the plugin jar?

Comment: The reason why it cannot find the spring-context is because the plugin uses a different classloader. Providing the correct classloader solves this issue.